# Explanation of htaccess redirections

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a piece of code in my htaccess that is working.(the code add a .html on an URL request that doesn't contain it.)

But I want to understand exactly how it's working. I understand most of it, but i'm not sure.

first line: it take everything that does not have the .html in it

second line: ??

third line: it exclude directory ?

fourth line: it add .html on each one that was not exclude.

Can someone explain each line please ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much got it all! So well done.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.html$
```

The first line is simply a condition that grabs the URI and checks to see if it includes `.html` on the end or not. If it does not, it will proceed onto line two and three, another two conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then proceed to the rewrite rule that follows on line four.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

As you stated, this is infact the Rewrite Rule that makes the change to your URL and adds `.html` onto the end of URLs. It does this using 301 redirection, which is a permanent form of redirection. It also includes the `[L]` flag which basically tells the server - *do not process any rules below in this iteration*.

I hope that helps to clear things up a bit for you. If you need further information then don't forget you can always check the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/).

Answer (score 1):

@Lag has already pointed out the meaning of these directives.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.html$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
> ```

However, this code won't actually work by itself in per-directory `.htaccess` files. It would result in an invalid redirect. Presumably, you also have a `RewriteBase` directive elsewhere in your `.htaccess` file? For example:

```
RewriteBase /
```

The reason for this is that the `$1` backreference will hold a *relative* URL-path (not starting with a slash). The directory-prefix is then added back, resulting in an invalid external redirect. The `RewriteBase` directive overrides the directory-prefix, making the redirect valid.

This could also be made marginally more efficient by testing for the abscence of the `.html` extension in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, rather than an additional condition. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,R=301]
```

This is because the `RewriteRule` directive is actually the first thing to be processed, *before* the `RewriteCond` directives that immediately precede it. Only when the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches, are the preceding `RewriteCond` directives processed. If the `RewriteCond` directives are successfull then the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is made.

This is also no longer dependent on the `RewriteBase` directive since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable already has the slash prefix.

If you use a `RewriteRule` *pattern* like `^(.*)$` then *every* request will be processed initially. The `RewriteCond` directive *later* fails, so the *substitution* is not made. However, it is always better to fail early, rather than late.

TIP: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching problems.

Comment: 1000 x better than my answer. Mark this one as correct.

Comment: @Lag Thanks, although my answer feels more like an _aside_, rather than answering the question directly - as you have done. (?)

Comment: Maybe so, but you picked up on an error that I didn't even consider which should help the OP directly and then offered a better solution to achieving what they needed. Either way, great answer :)